# Replace multiple strings in a single record using sql server

Tags: sql-server, replace, case

I have an html string stored as a record:

```
<div>          
<p>##RecipientFirstName##,</p>          
<p>##CustomerProjectOwnerName## with ##CustomerName## has approved your...</p>         </div>
```

I want to replace the items inside the hash tags with actual names stored in the person table. I have tried this but it returns 3 different records. I need one record returned with the items inside the hash tags replaced with the Replace statement. My code:

```
SELECT mtg.Template,  REPLACE(mtg.Template, '##RecipientFirstName##',(SELECT p.FirstName FROM dbo.Person p WHERE p.PersonId = 16)) , 
                      REPLACE(mtg.Template, '##CustomerProjectOwnerName##',(SELECT p.FirstName FROM dbo.Person p WHERE p.PersonId = 16))   
 FROM dbo.MessageTypeGlobal mtg
WHERE mtg.MessageTypeGlobalId = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest your replace statements:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
               REPLACE(mtg.Template, '##RecipientFirstName##', p.FirstName), 
       , '##CustomerProjectOwnerName##', p.FirstName) 
FROM dbo.MessageTypeGlobal mtg
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT FirstName FROM dbo.Person WHERE PersonId = 16
) p
WHERE mtg.MessageTypeGlobalId = 1
```

I've used cross apply to prevent the need to write the subquery over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do (if you need different subqueries):

```
select customtemplate = replace(replace(replace(mtg.Template
    , '##CustomerProjectOwnerName##'
      , (select p.FirstName from dbo.Person p where p.PersonId = 16) )
    , '##RecipientFirstName##'
      , (select p.FirstName from dbo.Person p where p.PersonId = 16) )
    , '##CustomerName##'
      , (select p.FirstName from dbo.Person p where p.PersonId = 16) )
 from dbo.MessageTypeGlobal mtg
where mtg.MessageTypeGlobalId = 1
```